# $M_n(R)/[M_n(R), M_n(R)] \cong R/[R,R]$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

If $R$ is an associative ring then $[R,R]$ is the subgroup generated by the elements $[r,s]= rs-sr,$ for $r,s\in R$.
Show that $Trace : M_n(R)\longrightarrow R/[R,R]$ induces an isomorphism
$$ M_n(R)/[M_n(R),M_n(R)] \longrightarrow R/[R,R]$$

What I have tried so far is this:
I have a map $trace : M_n(R) \longrightarrow R$ the usual trace which is surjective
Then $j : R\longrightarrow R/[R,R]$ which is also surjective.

So I have a surjection $Trace$ ($(j\circ trace))$ form $ M_n(R)\longrightarrow R/[R,R]$

Now I need to show that Kernel(Trace) is my $[M_n(R),M_n(R)] $

Since $trace [AB-BA] \in [R,R]$ I have one way containment which is:
$$ [M_n(R),M_n(R)] \subset Kernel(Trace)$$

I am having trouble in proving $$Kernel(Trace)\subset [M_n(R),M_n(R)]$$

What I mistakenly proved is that for any $r\in [R,R]$ there exists $A,B \in M_n(R)$ such that $trace(AB-BA) = r$. Which doesn't help me.

So if you guys could help me out I will be delighted. Thank you.

Comment: [Here is a proof](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/MathH110/trace0.pdf) that $\ker(\mathrm{trace}) \subset [M_n(R),M_n(R)]$ when $R = \Bbb C$; I don't know if that extends to arbitrary associative rings

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you!! Will try to use this fact for arbitrary rings.

Comment: The sentence "Show that trace... induces an isomorphism" is meaningless if you don't specify isomorphism of which structures. There are (at least) 3 natural structures arising here: associative algebra (for the product), Lie algebra (for the bracket), and plain vector space...

Comment: @YCor, thank you for your valuable comment.I think since $R$ is a ring $R/[R,R]$ will be an abelian group under addition and since trace is an additive map I am looking for a group isomorphism, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View both $M_n(R)$ as a free left $R$-module with basis $(E_{ij})_{1\le i,j\le n}$. This trace map is obviously a $R$-module homomorphism (for all $n\ge 0$). It is obviously surjective for $n\ge 1$.

It remains to prove injectivity ($n\ge 0$). This means one has to prove that if some element $M\in M_n(R)$ has its trace in $[R,R]$ then it belongs to $[M_n(R),M_n(R)]$. Note that this is the case for $M=E_{ij}=[E_{ii},E_{ij}]$, and for $M=E_{ii}-E_{jj}=[E_{ij},E_{ji}]$. This allows to reduce to the case when $M=rE_{11}$, with $r\in [R,R]$, say $r=\sum [a_i,b_i]$: then $M$ equals $\sum [a_{i}E_{11},b_iE_{11}]$.

Comment: (The highbrow proof of all this is that Hochschild homology is Morita invariant, and $R$ and $M(n,R)$ are Morita equivalent.)